# How to create a temporary table in ORACLE with READ ONLY access

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using `CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` script to create a temporary table in the oracle DB but its showing `SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`. I Want to create a temp table with Read only access. Plz help me out in this.

What we are trying to achieve is:

1. We have to create a table in the destination database which is always GreenPlum.
2. In source database(Oracle) we are getting a select query from the USER for example: "select * from ABC A join DEF D on A.Col1=D.col1" then we are creating TEMP TABLE(In case of Oracle) on top of it for example "CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE table101 AS (select * from ABC A join DEF D on A.Col1=D.col1)".
3. Then using this TEMP table we get the required information from INFORMATION_SCHEMA for example "select * from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name='table101' ".By this we will get the column_name,data_type,character_maximum_length etc information. Using this information we can get "create table Statement" using Javascript .
4. Then we store this Create table statement in a variable & run it in Execute Row script(Step in pentaho data integration tool) which will create the Table in the destination DB.
5. Problem is that we have read only access in oracle. now what to do.

NOTE: In short, we are creating a table in the destination DB using the select statement from the source DB. Means structure of the table in Dest DB depends on the select query in Source DB.

Comment: why dont you try to create a table on read only table space?

Comment: I am new to Oracle can u plzz give me some example to create a table on read only table space...Actually I need to create a temp table from a select query

Comment: `CREATE TABLE TEMP1 tablespace new_tablespace_name
 AS SELECT * FROM SOMETHING;` and then `ALTER TABLESPACE new_tablespace_name READ ONLY;` I could not test now. But if this works then I can write it as an answer.

Comment: what is "new_tablespace_name "...I am getting tablespace 'NEW_TABLESPACE_NAME' does not exist

Comment: you need to create one. or use an existing one. Then try to use that name.

Comment: I have read only access.. I cannot create

Comment: OK. Now I undersdtand. Then you cannot create any table. Only select is possible. So do a select and export it into a file.

Answer (score 0):

If the target database is also an oracle database then you should be able to set up a database link there to the source database and use a "CREATE TABLE AS SELECT * FROM +source table+@+database link+;"

Whoops, I just noticed that this is from 2014. Oh well, maybe it well help future inquirers.